# Event Listener via iframe between two Angular 8+ Apps

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe

We are running 2 angular apps via iframe in the browser window. I would like to create some sort of event listener in my angular app, that is going to listen specific events coming from other iframe.

how can I achieve that? I mean functions are ready to use, but somehow they need to be triggered (from another angular app) and handled(in my angular 8 app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you can communicate between 2 iframes without any server intervention is by using `window.postMessage()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: I could not implement this. I dont know why, but in visual studio code it gives an error when I am trying to implement this inside the component. I could not find any example yet for those who did this in angular.

Comment: `constructor(@Inject('window') window: Window}) {}`

Comment: https://www.leonelngande.com/how-to-get-a-reference-to-the-window-object-in-an-angular-8-application/

it doesnt compile with the method stated above.

Comment: wrap the window as any like this: `(window as any).postMessage...`

Comment: Thank you for the comments, do you have working sample? because I could not manage to make things work.